# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: map is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```
const initializeBoard = () => {
    const initialBoard = [];
    
  stores.map((store) => initialBoard.push({lable: store.shop}));
//   stores.map(function(value, _key) {
//     initialBoard.push({lable: value.shop});
// });
  return initialBoard;
}
const nestedMenuitems = ref([

    {
        label: 'Shipments',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-envelope',
        items: initializeBoard()
    },
  
]);
onMounted(() => {
    ApiService.getStores().then((data) => {
        stores.value = data;
        //return  stores.map((store) => store.push({lable: store.shop}));

        console.log(stores);

//         stores.value.map(function(value, _key) {
            
//             list.push({lable: value.shop});

//      console.log(value.shop);
//    });
    //    stores.value.forEach((store) => { return {
            
    //  }});
     
    });
    
});
```

i trying to fetch data to pass value   (items: initializeBoard()) this line.this will be show
items: [
{
label: 'Tracker',

```
        },
        {
            label: 'Map',
           
        },
        {
            label: 'Manage',
          
        }
    ]
```

this format.but i get a error in.Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: map is not a function
this line (  stores.map((store) => initialBoard.push({lable: store.shop}));)
how to solve this?

Comment: If you don't use Typescript, you can ignore that one.

Comment: this should be `stores.value.map(...)` and not `stores.map(...)`